# How can I query/invoke a ledger outside CLI container?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I have built a network following "Building your first network" tutorial. I have also managed to run the network on multiple hosts (example: peer0 on PC1, peer1 and CLI on PC2).

What I know is that I can query or invoke the ledger in the CLI container. 
Can I do this outside CLI container on PC2? For example, I need to query it on PC1. What should I do?

Comment: You can use a client SDK ( nodejs/ GoLang/ Java) to make an open connection with the ledger on PC1 and submit invoke or query transactions.

Comment: Can you provide me with a good tutorial? @VarunAgarwal

Comment: What have you used as the chain code language? Or have you used Hyperledger Composer?

Comment: I followed Building your first network tutorial and it all worked. I didn't install Composer. I don't know how to continue... @VarunAgarwal

Comment: Have you managed to install a chaincode? Because based on the chaincode used the client SDK and method will vastly differ. Can you link what you followed, this way I will know exactly where you dropped off and can share relevant info.

Comment: Yes I instantiated and installed a chaincode with go language. I followed the "Building your first network tutorial" [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/build_network.html) . 
I managed to run the network on multiple hosts (Abdul Wahab tutorial). Now I don't know how to continue... @VarunAgarwal